# How to pass this name=`"item_number_'.$num.'" in POST

Tags: php, post, input

This thing is inside a function, if conditions true do the `echo` below

```
<?php
ge() {
   while (conditions) {
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number_' . $num . '" value="' . $num . '">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $num . '" value="' . $get_row['name'] . '">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $num . '" value="' . $value . '">';
      }
   }
?>
```

I need to call the name of the input tag in post for mailing purpose. how to pass this in post? do i have to use array as this is inside a while loop and gives output based on the number of time looped.

---

@bestprogrammerintheworld  The entire function is  ..

```
<?php
function checkout() {
  $num = 0;
  foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
      if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_') {
        $id  = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name) - 5));
        $get = mysql_query('SELECT id,name FROM products WHERE id=' . mysql_real_escape_string((int) $id));
        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {

          $num++;
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="' . $num . '">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $get_row['name'] . '">';
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="quantity_" value="' . $value . '">';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: you can get the key and value of each post variable using a for each loop: foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)

Comment: How does the whole while-loop look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets in your input's name, like this:

```
ge(){ 
  while(conditios){
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item['.$num.'][number]" value="'.$num.'">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item['.$num.'][value]" value="'.$get_row['name'].'">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="item['.$num.'][quantity]" value="'.$value.'">';
 } }
```

This way, you'll have your `$_POST` looking like this:

```
$_POST => array(
    'item' => array(
        1 => array(
            'number' => '42',
            'value' => 'asdf',
            'quantity' => '1337'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'number' => '43',
            'value' => 'asdfg',
            'quantity' => '1338'
        )
    )
)
```

And guess what buddy, you'll iterate over your items in no time.

Comment: can you please explain it . iam a beginner find it very confusing !

Comment: @RajaMOhammed By using square brackets in the input's name you define arrays. When the form is submitted, PHP is clever enough to serve your data in the same array structures as you defined them with the input names (as i displayed in the second block). You can access them like this: `$_POST['item'][1]['value']`. This way you get the value of your first sql result. `$_POST['item'][2]['quantity']` would be the quantity of the second sql result. Using `foreach($_POST['item'] as $row)` you can iterate over your items.